# IOT platform and Salesforce

Tags: integration, iot

I am doing poc right now. We are building a sample poc for client **where we need Firebase that will receive data from hardware/sensors.** after that we need to **transfer data from Firebase to SFDC**. if there is any way in which we can migrate data, then we are good to go with firebase. please guide us on this.

Also if firebase is not supported for integration with SFDC **which all IOT platforms can be integrated with SFDC?**